# where stuffs like $D^pf(x):V\to Mult (V^p,W)$ is given

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Can one please suggest some book where things like derivative of a function maps to multilinear form is given ? I mean like where stuffs like $D^pf(x):V\to Mult (V^p,W)$ is given (where $f:E\subset V \to W$)

Comment: I believe Lang's undergraduate analysis book has some of this.  You might also be interested in my Multivariable Calculus course, which covers this material (although perhaps maybe a bit less generally than you want): http://ximera.osu.edu/course/kisonecat/m2o2c2/course/activity/welcome/

Answer (score 0):

You could look at a classic text like Fleming, *Functions of Several Variables* or Spivak, *Calculus on Manifolds*.  When your math muscles are more developed, there's the classic Dieudonne, *Foundations of Modern Analysis*  (not for the faint of heart).  Google the web for these ... you'll find low cost sources if you try.

Comment: I had spivak but I couldn't find what I wanted, anyways lemme check other ones

Comment: Differential Forms with Applications to Physical Sciences (Flanders) is also a nice survey, readily available online,  that's not attempting rigor but is good for stimulating ideas and understanding.